# raft balling up

Tags: print-quality, rafts, flashforge-adventurer-4

Suddenly, I can't seem to print anything on my Flashforge Adventurer 4. No matter what I try, the raft looks like this. I'm re-calibrated and tried all kinds of different heat/speed settings. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Hi Shawn, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! You don't give us much to work with, please [edit] the material you use, temperatures and speeds. Also state whether it used to work or never worked at all (`suddenly` hints that it used to work before). Did something change if it worked before? Also note that rafts are seldom needed, it is a relic from the past (only use it when you are printing materials that shrink a lot). If you need a raft for PLA, this indicates that there may be different issues at play, e.g. bed levelling and initial distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the suggestions.
My problem ended up being that the filament tube was loose (not screwed in all the way) into the extruder head. Eventually, the printer started giving me errors about irregular printhead readings and to check it. The print head was loose so I took the whole thing apart and put it back together tightly. My next print was perfect.

Comment: Glad you solved it and took the time to post an answer, this may help others in the future too! Happy printing!